# <button> execute mysql query on click

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and I am trying to execute a remove query when the remove button is clicked. At the moment the current  if statement is not triggered, so how can I trigger the if statement from a button and how can I get the id of the button that was tapped?

```
<?

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
         echo  "<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>";  
         echo  "<td>" . $row["teamName"] . "</td>";   
         echo  "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>";
         echo  "<td>" . $row["country"] . "</td>";
         echo  "<td>" . $row["birthday"] . "</td>";
         echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default ' aria-label='Left Align'>Edit</button>   ";
        echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn btn-danger' aria-label='Left Align' name='remove' value='remove'>Remove</button></td>";


    }
 ?>

if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
    $removeQuery = "UPDATE Players Where id='ID PRESSED?'";
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

Comment: Turn the button into a link with the $_GET variable, **delete.php?id=??** then grab the id its deleting and set it as the id in the query. @Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply change the button to link and get the id using `$_GET`

```
 <?php

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
     echo   "<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>";  
     echo   "<td>" . $row["teamName"] . "</td>";   
     echo   "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>";
     echo   "<td>" . $row["country"] . "</td>";
     echo   "<td>" . $row["birthday"] . "</td>";
     echo   "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default ' aria-label='Left Align'>Edit</button>   ";
     // change yourpage.php to the page that executes the query
     echo  "<a href='yourpage.php?del=".$row['id']."' class='btn btn btn-danger' aria-label='Left Align' name='remove' value='remove'>Remove</button></td>";    
 }


 if(isset($_GET['del'])){
     $id = (int)$_GET['del'];
     $removeQuery = "UPDATE Players Where id = $id";
     header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
         echo  "<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>";  
         echo  "<td>" . $row["teamName"] . "</td>";   
         echo  "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>";
         echo  "<td>" . $row["country"] . "</td>";
         echo  "<td>" . $row["birthday"] . "</td>";
         echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default ' aria-label='Left Align'>Edit</button>   ";
         echo "<a href='yourpage.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='btn btn btn-danger'>Remove</a></td>";
    }

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $removeQuery = "UPDATE Players SET col_name = value WHERE id=".$id." ";
    $result = mysql_query($removeQuery);
    if($result) {
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
}

?>
```